# PHP UPDATE Unknown column 'name' in 'field list'

Tags: php, mysql

I seem to be having an issue when it come to updating a database using PHP. I keep getting the error:

```
ERROR: Could not able to execute UPDATE settings SET value='0' WHERE id='2'. Unknown column 'value' in 'field list'
```

but the Column "value" does exist, and I have tried what people have previously said when asking the same question about it error but nothing has worked so far. what would be the reason behind this not working?

Full Code:

```
require 'config.php';

$link = mysqli_connect("LocalHost", "PSRPCADM", "999989Ki9?", "PSRPC");



// Check connection

if($link === false){

    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());

}



// Escape user inputs for security
if(isset($_POST['Monday']) &&
$_POST['Monday'] == 'Yes')
{
$monday = "1";
}
else
{
$monday = "0";
}   



// attempt insert query execution


$sql = "UPDATE settings SET value='$monday' WHERE id='2'";




if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){

echo "it worked";


} else{

    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);

}



// close connection

// close connection

mysqli_close($link);
```

Comment: Could you show us table schema from `settings` table?

Comment: [Photo of Structure](https://gyazo.com/a1676f7f44e4608821fdf80b64b4269d)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
$sql = "UPDATE `settings` SET `value`='".$monday."' WHERE id='2'";
```

hope this help

Answer (score 2):

`value` is a keyword in mysql you can try to use  quote character  between `value`

```
"UPDATE settings SET `value`='$monday' WHERE id='2'"
```

[Keywords and Reserved Words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html)

Comment: It does make the Error go away as such, it just brings another error

ERROR: Could not able to execute UPDATE settings SET 'value'='0' WHERE id='2'. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''value'='0' WHERE id='2'' at line 1

Comment: using ` instead of ' just brings me back to my original error

Comment: this is still bringing me back to the original error

Comment: Is there any trigger in your table? Because it worked in sqlfiddle

Comment: If you're still getting that error after using backticks I'm guessing your column name has a space before or after it (or between the backtick and the text). Please update your question with the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE settings;`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "UPDATE settings SET value='$monday' WHERE id='2'";
```

In this line you're inputting the string '$monday', not the content of $monday. Perhaps the error was thrown because in the database 'value' don't support strings. Couldn't find any other errors.

Comment: the field did accept strings but it still had the same error